# Error with stty and STM32F4-DISCO (fourQ-package)

Tags: arm, ubuntu-16.04, stm32f4discovery, stty, peripherals

I recently downloaded the v3 of the FourQlib [1], build the FourQlib and wanted to test if everything went well.

First of all, my system: 
Windows 10 (host) with MinGW, ARM Toolchain, MSYS, ...
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Guest) (gcc, arm toolchain, ...)
VirtualBox
STM32F429ZI-Disco

The source [1] includes the directory "FourQ_ARM", when compiling you have to start the "monitor.sh" [2] file in a terminal. Since they (Longa et al.) link to "ttyUSB0" I'll checked, if there is any device registered in Ubuntu. Since my µC ist registered as "stlinkv2_2 I changed this symbolic link "/dev/ttyUSB0 -> /dev/stlinkv2_2".

If I run the monitor.sh, the beginning will turn me in an error:
stty -F /dev/stlinkv2_2 
leads to the error "Vorgang nicht zulässig" which means something like "Operation not allowed"

Could someone explain me, why I get this error and how to get this shell-script work?

[1] https://github.com/Microsoft/FourQlib

[2] https://github.com/Microsoft/FourQlib/blob/master/FourQ_ARM/tests_Cortex-M4/monitor.sh

Comment: do you have a /dev/ttyACM0 when connected?  if so what if you use minicom to connect to that?

Comment: Hey, it just turned out, that I have to connect it through TTL to USB-converter. Since I did it, the device is listed as "ttyUSB0". If I launch "monitor.sh" it does nothing. Looks like it is stacked in a limitless loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is: Using extra hardware with an old driver. Using TTL to USB-converter.

If someone needs to use the FourQlib on a STM32F407, use their USART and monitoring tools. On different processors you need to choose different USART pins. Those with a display connected allready use those pins.